Append information to the output of an existing command
A former colleague gave me these two PowerShell scripts to run, log, and monitor a continuous ping test:
Run & Log:
ping.exe -l 1500 -t W2K16svr|Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} | out-file C:\Temp\PingTest.txt -Encoding UTF8

Monitor (in another PS instance):
Get-content C:\Temp\PingTest.txt -tail 10 -wait

This works great, but I need to check a user with a laptop who often has to switch to WiFi, so I need the output to record the connection type (Ethernet or Wifi) so I can exclude the latter.
I've figured out I can get the connection type with this:
get-netconnectionprofile | select -ExpandProperty InterfaceAlias

… but what I can't figure out is how to append that to the ping output. Everything I've tried so far errors out.
Is it possible to do what I want, and if so, how?

You mean something like "{0} - {1} - {2}" -f (Get-Date), $_, [string] (get-netconnectionprofile).InterfaceAlias?

What should happen if multiple connection profiles are found?

@MathiasR.Jessen: It's one user with just one profile AFAIK. It seems to be working fine anyway. :)


You can include the information in the string you're already synthesizing via -f, the format operator:
"{0} - {1} - {2}" -f (Get-Date), $_, [string] (Get-NetConnectionProfile).InterfaceAlias

Note:

The [string] cast ensures that, even if there happen to be multiple connection profiles, only a single string is returned, taking advantage of how PowerShell stringifies arrays, namely by space-concatenating their (stringified) elements (e.g., [string] @('foo', 'bar') becomes 'foo bar').

Instead of piping to Select-Object -ExpandProperty, direct property access is performed on the output from Get-NetConnectionProfile, via enclosure in (...). This is more concise and efficient, and even works with multiple output objects, courtesy  of PowerShell's member-access enumeration.


